# Hazelcast client connection to mocked Hazelcast instance

Tags: java, hazelcast

Is there any way to make HazelcastClient instance can connect to Mocked Hazelcast Instance.Am Mocking Hazelcast Instance like below

```
TestHazelcastInstanceFactory factory = new TestHazelcastInstanceFactory();
HazelcastInstance instance = factory.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

But the Client instance is not able to connect to instance created above.Created client like below

```
HazelcastInstance instance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

Is there any way so that i can mock even the client instance

Answer (score 1):

Did you try passing `5700` as an initial port to the constructor? Check different options at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/test/TestHazelcastInstanceFactory.java

Comment: its only working if i start both my server and client at same time i mean through same java class

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `com.hazelcast.client.test.TestHazelcastFactory`? It has  `newHazelcastClient(ClientConfig config)`. This simple sample works for me:

```
 @org.junit.Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        server = hazelcastFactory.newHazelcastInstance(new Config());
        client = hazelcastFactory.newHazelcastClient();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDistributedMapOps() {
        IMap map = client.getMap("map1");
        map.put("key", "value");
        System.out.println("Map Size: "+map.size());
    }

    @org.junit.After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        client.shutdown();
        server.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Yes i tried this.But the problem is the server is starting on 5001 port and the client is still trying to contact 5701.Basically i need to mock both server and client

Comment: any other soultion @wildnez